# Grouping using percentiles

Tags: spss, dataset, quantiles, independence, deciles

I did visual binning process in spss and made three cutpoints like in this image:
[image]

I did check off included

I want to know the percentage range or value for each group.

If I describe it in this way is it correct, The percentage values?

Group 1/ equal or less than 25
Group 2/ 26-50 %
Group 3/ 51-75 %
Group 4/ 76%+ or above 75%

Did I describe the percentage values correct?

This program is spss

Thanks

Comment: Within limits, the method of binning is usually up to you. Whatever works best for the purpose at hand. // Your quantile method results in only four bins. That might not be enough bins if my purpose were, for example, to make a useful histogram. // Also, f0r some purposes, it is nice to have bin boundaries at "round" numbers, which you wouldn't usually get using quartiles.

Comment: @BruceET thank you very much for your answer, four bins is suitable for my research but my question was if I checked off included would my percentage values be like I described? Thank you

Comment: @BruceET I mean I want to write percentage values for each group but I don't know if what I wrote is correct

Comment: You don't give enough detail about your sample to answer that for sure. Looks OK. if you have 16 ovservations, sorted in order $ 45, 47, 48, 49, 51, 51, 52, 52, 53, 55, 56, 56, 57, 58, 59, 72,$ then R gives quartiles $45.00, 50.50, 52.50, 56.25, 72.00,$ which you might want to simplify slightly to use integer and half-integer bin endpoints.

Comment: @BruceET In spss if you make 3 cutpoints it gives three quartiles q1 which is 25%, Q2 is 50% and Q3 is 75%, I have 100 scores and I sorted them in order. So if describe the percentage values this way it is correct? Group 1 within 25 percentile, group 2 within 26-50 percentile, group 3 51-75 percentile, group 4 above 75 or 76+ percentile. I know the quartile values 25,50 and 75 but I'm not sure if I wrote the percentage values in relation to the groups in correct way.

Answer (score 1):

In my view this is not good statistical practice.  Percentiling should only be used when there is a competition.  For example, naiive teachers in high school grade "on the curve" to place a fixed proportion of students in each grade, not respecting the simple fact that performance should be judged on an absolute scale and not according to how many students perform like you.  Another example would be if resources are fixed and you can only affort to feed a certain proportion of people.  You might rank them in descending order of need and start at the top.

The situation you have is far from a setting where competition is the driving force.  Respect the original values.  Use an efficient statistical technique such as a nonparametric smoother to analyze them.  For more see https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/categorizing-continuous-variables.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: On this site thanks is expressed by upvoting comments/answers.  Thanks for the thanks though.